# What is the greatest speed he can reach with an acceleration of 5.00 g before blacking out?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

A jet fighter pilot wishes to accelerate from rest at 5.00 g to reach Mach-3 (three times the speed of sound) as quickly as possible. Experimental tests reveal that he will black out if this acceleration lasts for more than 5.00s . Use 331m/s for the speed of sound. What is the greatest speed he can reach with an acceleration of 5.00 g before blacking out?

What I have done is:

Using the formula of acceleration, $a=(\Delta v)/(\Delta t) = (\Delta v)/5 sec$

Then, I plugged in 5 g into a. $5.00 g=(\Delta v)/ 5 sec$

I assume that the final velocity is $3(331 meters/sec)$ because the fighter pilot wants to reach Mach-3.

So, I have $5.00 g = (3(331) - v_0)/5$. And this is where I am stuck.

Can one tell me how to continue from here, or if I am completely wrong?

Comment: I answered this problem when it was posted on Math Stackexchange. See [Answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485930/what-is-the-greatest-speed-he-can-reach-with-an-acceleration-of-5-00-g-before-bl)

Answer (score 2):

Read the problem statement carefully. What is it asking you for? (time, acceleration, initial speed, final speed, etc.) Also consider, what information about the pilot's actual motion (not just what he would like his motion to be) are you given in the problem? (time, acceleration, initial speed, final speed, etc.)